# Cloud Data Fusion: Is there a way we can trigger or schedule a reusable pipeline (build with macro) with different config files at the same time?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

Is there a way in Cloud Data Fusion that we can trigger or schedule a instance of a reusable pipeline code (build with macro) with different config files at the same time?

That is to trigger the same pipeline code with different config files and with these pipelines have different schedule.

or do i have to duplicate the reusable pipeline code for each config file? then what is the use of making the pipeline reusable?

In other words, Would like to know if we can schedule parallel runs of one reusable pipeline with different runtime arguments?

I did search online but couldnt find an answer.

Comment: Does this \[Link\](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/overview) will help you ?

Comment: no.. the link is just an overview of cloud data fusion.. I would like to know if we can schdule parallele runs of one reusable pipeline with different runtime arguments?

Comment: You can go through this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline), to change the configuration of each pipeline. Could you please elaborate on the requirement of scheduling the parallel runs ?

Answer (score 0):

You may trigger a pipeline more than once thru http.requests

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data={key: value}, json="")

url     :"{base_url}namespaces/{namespace name}/start"
headers :{"Authorization": get_token, "Accept": "application/json"}
data    :Should include appId,programType,programId,runtimeargs in key value format.
```

Below wrapper UI to understand/test http request

```
https://<cdf instnace url..datafusion.googleusercontent.com>/cdap/httpexecutor
```